# Why is Flatbutton underlined in red?

Tags: flutter, dart

It was working properly until recently I[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEUZJ.jpg) upgraded the dart sdk using some commands(im a total newbie to flutter) and then it suddenly started showing error and the code wouldn't compile.

I tried to update the Dart sdk to the latest version because the Intl dependency for the world time app i'm creating didn't work in that older version. But later this problem arose.

Comment: Even with an old version of Flutter, the name of the widget was `FlatButton`, not `Flatbutton`.  Capitalization matters.

Answer (score 1):

The FlatButton Widget has been replaced by the TextButton Widget [details](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/buttons)

```
TextButton.icon(
  onPressed: () {
     // do something on click
  },
  icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
  label: const Text("Click me"),
),
```

Comment: sure thing, you very welcome. Please also check if you use the outdated buttons:
- RaisedButton (now ElevatedButton)
- OutlineButton (now OutlinedButton)